# android MapView v2 throws: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've researched in stackoverflow and google to find solution but didn't find...

I have a Fragment (Support) and a MapView in it. And it throws this error.
SupportsMapFragment works normally. It means there's no problem with google api console or something like that.

I've added onResume, onPause etc. methods to fragment's appropriate methods. But nothing changes.

this is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="[my package name]"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="[my package name].MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        ...

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="[my key]" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#345"
    tools:context=".LandingFragment" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    ...
```

Can anybody explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a fragment to represent your Map on the XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Like on this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: If you are using the Android Support Library to support old android versions, you need to use the *Support elements... like the SupportMapFragment instead of use directly the MapView. How are you handling the map on your activity? Can you add your java code on your question?